# How to do autocomplete for Dynamic Inputs in Jquery, Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am doing Accounts Project in Laravel. In Payments Entry Screen, i want to add multiple ledger in this screen using autocomplete. i do autocomplete only first field based on id. How to do Remaining Field based on dynamic id or suggest any good method.

```
     <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
         <tr>
         <td width="50%">
        <input type="text" class="form-control boxed" name="transledger[]" id="transledger1" ></td>
         <td width="50%">
         <input type="text" class="form-control boxed" name="creditamt[]" id="creditamt1">
         </td>
         </tr>
    <tr>
         <td width="50%">
        <input type="text" class="form-control boxed" name="transledger[]" id="transledger2" ></td>
         <td width="50%">
         <input type="text" class="form-control boxed" name="creditamt[]" id="creditamt2">
         </td>
         </tr>

    <tr>
         <td width="50%">
        <input type="text" class="form-control boxed" name="transledger[]" id="transledger3" ></td>
         <td width="50%">
         <input type="text" class="form-control boxed" name="creditamt[]" id="creditamt3">
         </td>
         </tr>
    .......
...........
...........
..........
    </table>
```

autocomplete Query

```
 <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {

    src = "{{ url('searchajax') }}";
     $("#transledger1").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,

    });
}); 



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows you how you can use autocomplete.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ is a great resource to implement "autocomplete".

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            var availableTutorials  =  [
               "Javascript",
               "Jquery",
               "Vue.js",
               "Meteor.js",
            ];
            $( "#automp" ).autocomplete({
               source: availableTutorials
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div class = "ui-widget">
         <p>Type "m" or "j"</p>
         <label for = "autocomp">Tags: </label>
         <input id = "automp">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```